# Issue with taking params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I grouped some Timesheet objects together using activerecord

```
scope :grouped_by_user_with_total_time, lambda {
  group(:user_id, :day).select('user_id, SUM(time_worked) AS time_total, day, editable, approvable, accepted, comments')
}
```

And after I did that, now when I try to call the approve method on the grouped objects I get the error

```
Couldn't find TimeSheet without an ID
```

And it highlights the third line in my method

```
def approve
@time_sheets = []
*t = TimeSheet.find(params[:time_sheets])**  
if t.instance_of?(Array)
  @time_sheets = t
else
  @time_sheets << t
end
successful = []
unsuccessful = []

@time_sheets.each do |timesheet|
  unless timesheet.approved
    timesheet.approve
    if timesheet.save
      successful << timesheet
    else
      unsuccessful << timesheet
    end
  end
end
```

I'm not very experienced with this and I am not sure how to check if my `params[:time_sheets]` is nil which might be the issue. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes params[:time_sheets] being passed as nil would cause this error.

```
def approve
if params[:time_sheets]
@time_sheets = []
*t = TimeSheet.find(params[:time_sheets])**  
if t.instance_of?(Array)
  @time_sheets = t
else
  @time_sheets << t
end
successful = []
unsuccessful = []

@time_sheets.each do |timesheet|
  unless timesheet.approved
    timesheet.approve
    if timesheet.save
      successful << timesheet
    else
      unsuccessful << timesheet
    end
  end
end
end
```

By adding a check with `if params[:time_sheets]` we can ensure the method only runs if the params[:time_sheets] is not nil. However it seems that you might be having a problem in passing your params. If you post your code where you show where you pass the params we could find out why it's passing nil.

Comment: Now I get `Couldn't find TimeSheet with id=approve`

Comment: This means params[:time_sheets] is passing the string 'approve'  Show the code where you are setting the params[:time_sheets]

Comment: why the downvote on this one? Please always comment on a downvote thanks